# What's wrong with this pseudocode for the synchronization barrier?

Tags: synchronization, barrier

What's wrong with this pseudocode for the synchronization barrier?

```
global (shared) count : integer := P

procedure central_barrier

  if fetch_and_decrement(&count) == 1
    
     count := P

  else

    repeat until count == P
```

What is wrong with the above code?

p= number of threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that it depends on the precise semantics of `fetch_and_decrement`.  And of other aspects of the (assumed) memory and execution models.  These things would need to be specified before one can *confidently* reason about the behavior of your pseudo-code.

A 2nd issue is that the threads will be busy-waiting.

A 3rd issue is that there *appears to be* a race condition.   Suppose that a thread immediately calls `central_barrier` after returning from a `central_barrier` call.  It could then execute the `fetch_and_decrement(&count)` *before* all of the other threads have had a chance to end their `repeat until count == P` loops.  If it does, then some of those threads will keep on looping and the barrier will deadlock.

Here is an example sequence with P == 3 threads that illustrates the race condition.

0. count starts at 3
1. Thread A calls central_barrier, count <- 2, enters loop.
2. Thread B calls central_barrier, count <- 1, enters loop.
3. Thread C calls central_barrier, count <- 0, resets count <- 3, returns.
4. Thread C immediately calls central_barrier *again*, count <- 2, enters loop.
5. Thread A, B and C are now all stuck in the loop because count == 2 and no other threads can change it.  They are all waiting for count == 3, and that will never happen.

Now if threads A and B are both able to test count between steps 3 and 4, then they will break out of the loop ... and all will be well.  But we can't *guarantee* that.  One or both may have been preempted or  descheduled.  (Imagine the case where there are more threads than physical cores to run them all.)

Comment: You can give an example for the third case. Thanks